# how to put the chapter name on the top of each pages?

Tags: latex

I begin with latex and I have this .tex document and I'd like to put on the top of each future pages the number and name of what chapter I am into.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

% Options possibles : 10pt, 11pt, 12pt (taille de la fonte)
%                     oneside, twoside (recto simple, recto-verso)
%                     draft, final (stade de dÃ©veloppement)

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % LaTeX, comprends les accents !
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Police contenant les caractÃ¨res franÃ§ais
\usepackage[francais]{babel}  % Placez ici une liste de langues, la
                              % derniÃ¨re Ã©tant la langue principale
\usepackage{amsthm}         %Pour faire des remarques sur des théorème en mathématique
\usepackage[lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% RÃ©duire les marges
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}

% \pagestyle{headings}        % Pour mettre des entÃªtes avec les titres
                              % des sections en haut de page

\title{\underline{\textbf{Rapport TER}}}           % Les paramÃ¨tres du titreÂ : titre, auteur, date
\title{%
  {\textbf{Rapport TER}} \\
  \large Chip-firing games}


\bigbreak
\bigbreak
\author{Sébastien Gouverneur}
% \date{}                       % La date n'est pas requise (la date du
                              % jour de compilation est utilisÃ©e en son
                  % absence)


\sloppy                       % Ne pas faire dÃ©border les lignes dans la marge

\begin{document}



\maketitle                    % Faire un titre utilisant les donnÃ©es
                              % passÃ©es Ã  \title, \author et \date
\newpage
% \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}    %Modifie le nom par default de la table des matières
\tableofcontents              % Table des matiÃ¨res
\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\newpage
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa




% \subsubsection{Titre}       % Encore plus petite


% \paragraph{Titre}           % Toutes petites sections (le nom \paragraph
                              % n'est pas trÃ¨s bien choisi)

% \subparagraph{Titre}        % La derniÃ¨re

% \appendix                   % CommenÃ§ons les annexes

% \section{Titre}             % Annexe A

% \section{Titre}             % Annexe B

% \listoffigures              % Table des figures

% \listoftables               % Liste des tableaux

\end{document}
```

For exemple the page 4/4 should begin with something like 
"Chapter 1. Introduction"
and for each next pages I'll add to my report, this notation will appear until I add another chapter and after that It will be for each next pages 
"Chapter2. blabla"
Is it possible to do something like that and what package / commande should I use to do It? Thanks by advance.

Comment: Why not including chapter number/title in headers, using for example [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package?

Comment: Oh thank you It worked well and It's what I expected. :)

Comment: @SebGouv Hi! Please remember to mark the answer below as accepted! :)

Answer (score 10):

Considering that you are using documentclass `report`, which is `oneside` by default, you may add [`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) in your preamble and then, just after `\begin{document}`, you may add:

```latex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
```

This is only a rough sketch, not including page numbering (that may stay in the header too) and fine styling of the header itself.